# Redirect url in route config in Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5.2

How to Redirect url in route config in Asp.net Mvc...

My controller is "Home" and action is "Categories"

My url is **localhost:49606/Home/Categories**

now i changed using routes below

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Categories",
            url: "Categories",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                            action = "Categories", 
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

New url is `localhost:49606/Categories`

But still `localhost:49606/Home/Categories` url is avilabe...

I want to redirect `localhost:49606/Home/Categories` to `localhost:49606/Categories`.

or

Hide url `localhost:49606/Home/Categories`.

Please suggest me good way to redirect url or hide?
I want to redirect url in route config file in asp.net mvc 5

Comment: Please show us the whole route config, because the order in which you define your routes is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Attribute routing.
In case of using attribute routing,you need to allow attribute routing to map your routes by adding following line in RouteConfig.cs

```
  routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

And then you can specify your route what you want.
no matter what your action name is.

```
    [Route("Categories")]
    public ActionResult GetCategories() 
    {
         return View();
    }
```

Comment: Need some more how to hide AreaName in Url.